# run create react app using craco build without magnification

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, craco

Anyone know how to get Create React app to build without magnification using craco ?

I have tried the following:

```
"build-dev": "BUILD_PATH='../build' env-cmd -f ../.env.development INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false craco build",
```

The above fails to run.

I also tried:

**craco.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.REACT_APP_PORT,
  },
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      "@mui/styled-engine": "@mui/styled-engine-sc",
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: false,
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        name: true,
      },
      runtimeChunk: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Above doesn't seem to do anything.